# Logic Error With Function to Manipulate Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

I'm in need of help determining where my logic error is. I'm writing a function in C++ that takes a singly linked list as input and is designed to remove odd integer nodes while duplicating even integer nodes:

EXAMPLES:

```
initial: 0  5  2  2  7  3  7  9  0  2
 ought2b: 0  0  2  2  2  2  0  0  2  2  
outcome: 0  0  2  2  2  2  0  0  2  2  

initial: 0
 ought2b: 0  0

initial: 1
 ought2b: (empty)
```

The problem i'm having is my outcome is right (as shown above)but after the second linked list the whole program quits and i'm getting an exit code 11 when I can only assume is a segmentation fault. I've rewritten the entire function 6+ times and mentally can't find where i've made a logic error as my code generally ends up looking similar with each iteration. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Code for function shown below.

```
void RemOddDupEven(Node*& headPtr){
    // Define two cursors to iterate through referenced list.
    Node *precursor = 0,
            *cursor = headPtr;

    // Error Checking | Check for reference to empty list.
    if(headPtr == 0){
        cerr << "RemOddDupEven() attempted on empty list" << endl;
        return;
    }

    while(cursor->link != 0){
        if(cursor->data%2 != 0){
            /// Odd node found in referenced list. Remove it.
            if(precursor == 0){
                // No previous. Removing first node.
                precursor = cursor;
                cursor = cursor->link;
                headPtr = cursor;
                delete precursor;
                precursor = 0;
            } else {
                Node* tempNodePtr = cursor;
                cursor = cursor->link;
                precursor->link = cursor;
                delete tempNodePtr;
            }
        } else {
            /// Even node found in referenced list. Duplicate it.
            if(precursor == 0){
                // No previous. Duplicate and insert before current node.
                Node* newNodePtr = new Node;
                newNodePtr->data = cursor->data;
                newNodePtr->link = cursor;
                headPtr = newNodePtr;
                precursor = cursor;
                cursor = cursor->link;
            } else {
                // There is a previous. Duplicate and insert before current.
                Node* newNodePtr = new Node;
                newNodePtr->data = cursor->data;
                precursor->link = newNodePtr;
                newNodePtr->link = cursor;
                precursor = cursor;
                cursor = cursor->link;
            }
        }

    }
    /// We are at last item in the list.
    if(cursor->data%2 != 0){
        /// Odd node found at end of referenced list. Remove it.
        precursor->link = 0;
        delete cursor;
        cursor = 0;
    } else {
        /// Even node found at the end of referenced list. Duplicte it.
        Node* newNodePtr = new Node;
        newNodePtr->data = cursor->data;
        precursor->link = newNodePtr;
        newNodePtr->link = cursor;
    }
}
```

Comment: ***I've rewritten the entire function 6+ times*** You really need to get an IDE with the ability to debug. You should not be rewriting your code making guesses to figure out what you implemented wrongly.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is step through the code with a debugger and find which line ends the program.  Then you can create a [mcve] that contains that line and reproduces the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is too complicated and it is difficult to investigate it because there are many special conditions within the function.

But at first glance it is evident for example that this code snippet

```
/// We are at last item in the list.
if(cursor->data%2 != 0){
    /// Odd node found at end of referenced list. Remove it.
    precursor->link = 0;
    delete cursor;
    cursor = 0;
} else {
```

is wrong.

Let's consider a list that has only one node that is the head node.

In this case the loop

```
while(cursor->link != 0){
    //...
}
```

will not be executed because `headPtr->link` is equal to `nullptr`. Also this mean that `precursor` is equal to 0 (it was set initially to 0 before the loop). So the expression statement

```
precursor->link = 0;
```

results in undefined behavior of the function.

At the same time this statement

```
    cursor = 0;
```

does not change the value of the `headPtr` because `cursor` and `headPtr` are two different objects and changing the value of one object does not influence on the value of another object.

The function implementation can look essentially simpler.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *link;
};

void initialize(Node * &head, const int a[], size_t n)
{
    Node **current = &head;

    while (*current) current = &(*current)->link;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        *current = new Node{ a[i], nullptr };
        current = &(*current)->link;
    }
}

void RemOddDupEven(Node * &head)
{
    Node **current = &head;

    while (*current)
    {
        if ((*current)->data % 2 == 0)
        {
            (*current)->link = new Node{ (*current)->data, (*current)->link };
            current = &(*current)->link->link;
        }
        else
        {
            Node *tmp = *current;
            *current = (*current)->link;
            delete tmp;
        }
    }
}

std::ostream & show(Node * &head, std::ostream &os = std::cout)
{
    for (Node *current = head; current; current = current->link)
    {
        os << current->data << ' ';
    }

    return os;
}

int main()
{
    Node *head = nullptr;
    int a[] = { 0, 5, 2, 2, 7, 3, 7, 9, 0, 2 };

    initialize(head, a, sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a));

    show(head) << std::endl;

    RemOddDupEven(head);

    show(head) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 5 2 2 7 3 7 9 0 2
0 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 2 2
```

Comment: Vlad thank you! I really appreciate the explanation. Can you elaborate on the reasoning behind using a pointer to a pointer?  Node **current = &head;

Comment: @AlexanderMaxwell In fact cursor is a reference to head in the C meaning of the indirection. Using a pointer to head we can change the head through the pointer. It is the same way as in a function like this void f( int * p ) { * p = 10; } /*...*/ int x = 5; f( &x ); std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;